# Different fill values for different factors in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, fill

I am trying to construct a bubble plot where one factor has a solid fill and the other is filled based on log fold change. I have a list of differentially abundant proteins with log fold change values between two time points (my two factors that I want to fill differently). I can fill the bubbles based on the log fold change (first plot) and based on time (second plot), but I would really like all the 2 am bubbles to be black/gray and all the 8 pm bubbles to be filled conditional on log fold change. Can this be done without making 2 graphs?

I am working in R v 3.3.2 with packages ggplot2 and ggthemes.

Time = 2 time points
ETS.category = protein functional category that essentially bins individual proteins into groups
sumnsaf = protein abundance value for each protein in each time point (scale for size of bubbles)

I cannot provide the dput output because it is too large for a post, but hopefully you get the idea from the first lines (I can provide the input file, if needed):

```
      Protein  Entry Protein.names LogFoldChange    ETS.category    Time
1  01554_comp1507_c0 Q9BLZ1    Luciferase        -1.581 bioluminescence 8:00 PM
2  01330_comp1408_c1 Q9BLZ1    Luciferase        -1.406 bioluminescence 8:00 PM
3 23772_comp16505_c1 Q9BLZ1    Luciferase        -1.355 bioluminescence 8:00 PM
4  01339_comp1414_c0 Q9BLZ1    Luciferase        -1.160 bioluminescence 8:00 PM
5  01279_comp1377_c0 Q9BLZ1    Luciferase        -1.093 bioluminescence 8:00 PM
6  01252_comp1362_c0 Q9BLZ1    Luciferase        -0.992 bioluminescence 8:00 PM
   xiphias1  xiphias2  xiphias3  xiphias4   xiphias5 xiphias6   sumnsaf
1  89.32287 138.36007 113.07703 100.67700  89.621533  55.3685  586.4270
2 360.74747 368.67670 369.56857 339.59370 188.797933 177.9319 1805.3163
3 121.36577 140.46653 140.11740 104.01390  32.485567   0.0000  538.4492
4   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000  15.78833  71.783467   0.0000   87.5718
5  45.70467   0.00000  76.76587  57.41630   9.734833   0.0000  189.6217
6  97.30740  98.25493 130.76463 132.09267 108.591567   0.0000  567.0112
```

For filling based on log fold change:

```
ggplot(prot.sum2) + geom_jitter(aes(x=Time, y=ETS.category, colour=LogFoldChange, size=sumnsaf), alpha=0.5, width=0.2, height=0.2) + labs(y='Protein Category') + geom_hline(yintercept=c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5), color='grey80') + theme_tufte()
```

[image: bubble plot with log fold change fill]

For filling based on time

```
ggplot(prot.sum2) + geom_jitter(aes(x=Time, y=ETS.category, size=sumnsaf, colour=factor(Time)), alpha=0.5, width=0.2, height=.2) + labs(y='Protein Category') + geom_hline(yintercept=c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5), color='grey80') + guides(size=guide_legend(title='Abundance')) +  scale_colour_manual(values=c('black', 'red')) + guides(colour=F) + theme_tufte()
```

[image: bubble plot with time fill]

Comment: in short, yes it can be done. first, please reformat your question as a minimal reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please properly format your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Highlighting your code and pressing `ctl+k` will be a good start, also include the output of `dput(prot.sum2)`

Comment: Can you provide your data? `dput(prot.sum2)`?

Comment: Are my edits sufficient? Thanks.